# Unity Ads Showing Only in Editor

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, ads, unityads

I'm trying to implement Unity Ads on my game that I'm planning on deploying on iOS, but for some reason they are only appearing in the editor (where it says "Everything Seems to be Working!") but every time I build to my iPhone 5s, the ads don't pop up.
Here is my script (to activate it I just attached it to a game-object in my scene):

```
 static int loadCount = 0;

 void Start()
 {
     if (loadCount % 3 == 0)  // only show ad every third time
     {
         ShowAd ();
     }
     loadCount++;
 }

 public void ShowAd()
 {
     if (Advertisement.IsReady())
     {
         Advertisement.Show();
     }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you add iOS as a platform in unity ads dashboard? just a guess

Comment: @Lestat Hi, yes, I did but it still doesn't  work.

Comment: Long time ago but how did you resolve it?